# PhoneGap Card.IO Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, card.io

I am using PhoneGap to build iOS app, when I use iOS 8.1 then scan the credit card or select enter manually, the below error happen then it crash my app, the function works fine on iOS 7.1. Please help us to resolve this .

Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already. (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x1701ce790>)
2014-11-29 15:36:07.853 Relapse[794:305970] transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation? (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x1701ce790>)

Thank you.

Comment: Discussion of this problem is happening here: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/83